# Set File Permissions to Default from Umask

Tags: shell-script, permissions, chmod, umask

https://geek-university.com/linux/set-the-default-permissions-for-newly-created-files/

So I want my `umask` (command) which in this case is `0002` to be subtracted (bitwise) from `666` for files and `777` default base permissions for folders. For example, the result here for a file would be 664.

This is so I can change the permissions of files I created with `chmod` using that new mask which is of course the default mask when you create a file with `touch` for example.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ echo 'ibase=8; obase=8; (( 0666 - 0002 ))' | bc
644
$ echo 'ibase=8; obase=8; (( 0777 - 0002 ))' | bc
775
```

Comment: This is good. Only problem is that for some reason on my machine I don't have `bc` installed and I can't install packages on this particular machine. For some reason I only have the `man` page for it installed but not the actual command itself. Sounds like a bug with my distro to me.

Comment: @QuantRise I tested this in Windows running WSL Debian, that didn't have `bc` installed either, I don't really know why.

Comment: Hm, dom0 of QubesOS here.